# height:100% margin white space/block problem

Tags: css, xhtml

I followed this [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) how-to, to implement a sticky footer. I was successful but noticed that the (min)-height:100%  has an negative effect on when I try to apply a margin-left of right to my primaryContent div.

At a certain height it causes a block of whitespace to show up. The only work-around I've found so far is to use padding instead of margin.
The height that this happens can be seen in my screenshot below. And I also notice if I remove the "background:inherit" line from #primaryContent div that the background of the container div stops at the same height that the margin white space problem occurs.

Any type of help is appreciated, links to the source code are:
[default.css](http://pastebin.com/xVXbPQQH)
[index.html](http://pastebin.com/LV32Qp9X)
[reset.css](http://pastebin.com/TqSTezZU)

Screenshot: 
[image: see screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very strage how they let that slip here is a fix :D

look for this in the default.css

```
html, body, #container { 
      height: 100%; 
}
```

replace it with

```
html, body { 
      height: 100%; 
}
```

Im not completely sure what the explanation for why this happens it could just be an css bug but there is always a work around.

*bada-bing* your done!

Answer (score 1):

Click the "Reference Link" at the bottom of your example URL....it points to the original source: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/.

If you click the "[How to Use the Sticky Footer Code](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html)", you'll find that because the way their/his solution is written - `padding` for height attributes is proper - not margins.

I read through the documentation a week or so ago - thought I saw that caveat. `<find>+padding` will take you right to the notation.

Comment: You're right I looked over that part. Thank you very much for your help!